# Django API showing big time latency while retrieving data

Tags: python, django, postgresql, angular, django-rest-framework

I am currently working on Angular2 and Django (python framework). i have created a simple API in django which shows me all record from database.
here is link of that API.

```
[https://djangoshopnroar.herokuapp.com/mobile/viewAll][1]
```

But when i call it from Angular 2. it gives me a time latency. worst thing i have only 10 records in my db. and it take almost 6-8 sec for that. i am using PostgreSQL database. 
Can anyone have idea why angular 2 is showing latency in time. or any suggestions how can i improve it? i will be very thankful for that.

here is my views file

```
from django.shortcuts import render

    #######################View all mobiles
@api_view(['GET'])
def getAll_Mobiles(request):
    try:
        Mobile_all = Mobile.objects.all()
    except Mobile.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)


    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = Mobile_Serializer(Mobile_all, many=True)  # many=True so it doesn't return only 1 JSON Object
        return Response(serializer.data)
    else:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    pass
```

Comment: Can you mention your view here.

Comment: Have you measured where the latency is coming from? If it's from the db then you should remove the python/angularjs/django/django-rest-framework tags, etc.

Comment: @MohammadMustaqeem here is my views file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it works slowly because your api return images as base64 string. You must move images from db to file system and in db store path for this files. Your api must return urls for this images instead of whole encoded image. For this you can use [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#imagefield)

Comment: "ou must move images from db to file system and in db store path for this files. " can you please any link where i can move images to file folder. and one thing more, in which format i will be sending images from angular 2